# Tracking value changes when editing a record in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to track value changes when editing a record. All fields on the form are unbound text box.

Below is a function that is used to insert a audit tracking record.

```
Public Function AuditChanges(RecordID As String, UserAction As String)

    Dim DB As Database
    Dim rst As Recordset
    Dim clt As Control
    Dim Userlogin As String

    Set DB = CurrentDb
    Set rst = DB.OpenRecordset("select * from tbl_audittrail", adOpenDynamic)

    Userlogin = Environ("username")

    Select Case UserAction

        Case "Edit"
            For Each clt In Screen.ActiveForm.Controls

                If (clt.ControlType = acTextBox _
                    Or clt.ControlType = accombox) Then
                    If Nz(clt.Value) <> Nz(clt.OldValue) Then
                        With rst
                            .AddNew
                            ![DateTime] = Now()
                            !UserName = Userlogin
                            !FormName = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
                            !Action = UserAction
                            !RecordID = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(RecordID).Value
                            !FieldName = clt.ControlSource
                            !OldValue = clt.OldValue
                            !Newvalue = clt.Value
                            .Update
                        End With
                    End If
                End If
            Next clt
    End Select

    rst.Close
    DB.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set DB = Nothing
End Function
```

Below is how I use the function:

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click()

    Set DB = CurrentDb
    Set rs = DB.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM ASID", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

        rs.Edit
        rs!ISIN = Me.ISIN
        rs!SECIDTYPE = Me.SECIDTYPE
        rs!ALTSECID = Me.ALTSECID
        rs.Update
        Call AuditChanges("ISIN", "Edit")

     End If

End Sub
```

The problem is when it calls AuditChanges, it goes directly from

```
If (clt.ControlType = acTextBox _
    Or clt.ControlType = accombox)
```

to `End If`

All fields on current form are unbound text boxes and you have to press an "Add" command button to actually add a record. I think there must be something wrong with the control type but I am not sure which control type should be used. Any idea?

Comment: Also, an unbound control doesn't have an _OldValue_.

Comment: But to update a record, I have to retrieve a record first then update certain fields on it except primary keys. In that case, value before update should be treated as OldValue, right? I am pretty new in coding, so forgive me if I make stupid mistake.

Comment: It's hard to say, but Andre is correct that there's no such thing as "accombox".  What you should probably do is put a line of code in there that says ' msgbox "Control Name: & clt.Name & ", ControlType: " & ctl.ControlType ' (without the single quotes) and put that in your loop.  This way you'll know what each control is called and what it's type is.  I'm thinking you'll figure out what you did wrong if you see this info for each control on your page.

Comment: I have corrected the control type. I still can't track my changes. Is there any other way to do that? All my changes are done in acTextBox and the code does not even try to compare the current value and old value. If that's because of unbound text box, any other way to track the chsnge? Thanks.

Comment: Why going through this hassle when Access give your table triggers? use table triggers/ data macro to automatically capture changes >= access 2010

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out.

Comment: It worked! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Start by putting [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) at the top of each module. 
It enforces variable declaration and reports undeclared or misspelled variables/constants at compile time. 
To have this automatically in new modules, set the [Require Variable Declaration](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/modules/options/index.html) option in the VBA Editor. 
This is really a must have for VBA development.

Then the compiler will tell you that `accombox` doesn't exist, it should be `acComboBox`

Without `Option Explicit`, `accombox` is initialized as NULL variant, and causes your entire `If` condition to be NULL, and therefore never be entered.

Comment: Thank you. I'll do that. But I don't think it will help because there is no combo box on the screen.